# How to pivot/transform table?

Tags: sql

I have a table.

Example:

| run_ts | user | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 1 |
| 1235 | A | 2 |
| 123 | B | 1 |
| 124 | B | 2 |

I want to transform it into

| first_run_ts | last_run_ts | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1235 | A |
| 123 | 124 | B |

How can i do it?

Comment: I assume this is `SQL Server`?

Comment: It could be MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic solution, I think you can use a combination of `MIN` and `MAX` with `GROUP BY`...see below:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(run_ts) AS first_run_ts,
    MAX(run_ts) AS last_run_ts,
    [user]
FROM 
    your_table
GROUP BY
    [user]
```

[A SQL Fiddle for a demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9b88/1)

Comment: Note that (generic) ANSI/ISO SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"user"`.